# Win2008 SRV Certutil csv option not present

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

I have an Enterprise Certificate Authority running well.

I am attempting to automate some monitoring tasks using batch files and the certutil.exe command.

After reading the documentation at: [certutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc732443.aspx#BKMK_view) and there is an option [csv] to export the results as a CSV.

But somehow, my version of W2008SRV does not have that option. It says the following:

> Uso:
>     CertUtil [Opciones] -view [Queue | Log | LogFail | Revoked | Ext | Attrib | CRL]
>     Volcar la vista de certificado
>       Queue -- Cola de solicitudes.
>       Log -- Certificados emitidos o revocados, además de solicitudes con error.
>       LogFail -- Solicitudes con error.
>       Revoked -- Certificados revocados.
>       Ext -- Tabla de extensiones.
>       Attrib -- Tabla de atributos.
>       CRL -- Tabla CRL.

```
Para mostrar la columna StatusCode de todas las entradas:
    -out StatusCode
Para mostrar todas las columnas de la última entrada:
    -restrict "RequestId==$"
Para mostrar el id. de solicitud y la disposición de tres solicitudes:
    -restrict "RequestId>=37,RequestId<40" -out "RequestId,Disposition"

Para mostrar los id. de filas y números CRL de todas las CRL de base:
    -restrict "CRLMinBase=0" -out "CRLRowId,CRLNumber" CRL
Para mostrar la CRL de base número 3:
    -v -restrict "CRLMinBase=0,CRLNumber=3" -out "CRLRawCRL" CRL
Para mostrar la tabla CRL completa:
    CRL
```

> Opciones:
>     -gmt              -- Mostrar horas como GMT
>     -seconds          -- Mostrar horas con segundos y milisegundos
>     -silent           -- Usar marcador silencioso para adquirir contexto criptográfico
>     -split            -- Dividir elementos ASN.1 incrustados y guardar en archivos
>     -v                -- Operación detallada
>     -privatekey       -- Mostrar los datos de la clave privada
>     -config Equipo\NombreCA   -- Cadena de nombre de CA y equipo
>     -restrict Lista de restricciones -- Lista de restricciones delimitadas por comas
>        Cada restricción consiste en un nombre de columna, un operador relacional y
>        una fecha, una cadena o un entero constante. El nombre de columna puede ir
>        precedido de un signo más o menos para indicar el criterio de ordenación.
>        Ejemplos:
>           "RequestId = 47"
>           "+RequesterName >= a, RequesterName < b"
>           "-RequesterName > DOMAIN, Disposition = 21"
>     -out Lista de columnas    -- Lista de columnas delimitadas por comas
>
> CertUtil -?              -- Mostrar una lista de verbos (lista de comandos)
>   CertUtil -view -?        -- Mostrar el texto de ayuda del verbo "view"
>   CertUtil -v -?           -- Mostrar todo el texto de ayuda de todos los verbos

There are 2 things to notice:

1. It's in spanish.
2. There is no [csv] option

Trying to use the csv option fails saying that it received incorrect parameters.

Is there someway I can install a version of certutil that does have the [csv] option?

Is there another easy to parse way to dump the info of the Certificate Services database?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this 2008 or 2008R2? The CSV option was introduced in 2008R2. If it's a Windows 2008 server, just run Certutil from a 2008R2 or higher machine (against that CA), and you should get the CSV option.

Comment: Thanks I will try as soon as I can get my hands on a 2008R2 installation and post my results.